# How to redirect the output to a writer in rhino?

Tags: rhino

Is it possible to redirect the output from the Context.evaluateString(...) to a Writer? I am looking for something that is similar to ScriptContext.setWriter (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html#setWriter%28java.io.Writer%29) provided with jdk 6.

Answer (score 0):

Rhino does not have concepts of standard input/output, so you have to assign the Writer to some variable. like this:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;

public class SetWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context c=Context.enter();
        ScriptableObject scope = c.initStandardObjects();
        StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "writer", writer);
        String source = "  writer.write('hello');  ";
        c.evaluateString(scope, source, "TEST", 1, null);
        System.out.println(writer.getBuffer());
    }
}
```

Or, you are using System.out.println in your script, consider using System.setOut before you run the script.